# Nginx configuration with wildcard LetsEncrypt certificate for sub domains

Tags: ssl, certificate, nginx, domain, letsencrypt

I'd like to configure nginx with wildcard LetsEncrypt certificate for dynamic sub domains - domains that will be emulated by web application.

Right now I have the following "static" domains:

```
example.com
sso.example.com
```

Based on the user content, the applciation will emulate the following domains:

```
anyname1.example.com
anyname2.example.com
...
{somename}.example.com
```

There are following nginx configs:

```
server {
        server_name example.com;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

        root /var/www/html/example;

        location / {
                root /var/www/html/example;
                index index.html index.htm;

                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    server_name example.com;

    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ;

    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
        server_name *.example.com;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/domains.example.com.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/domains.example.com.error.log;

        root /var/www/html/example;

        location / {
                root /var/www/html/example;
                index index.html index.htm;

                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

#       listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
#       listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    server_name *.example.com;

    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

#    listen 80 ;
#    listen [::]:80 ;

    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
        server_name sso.example.com;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/sso.example.com.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/sso.example.com.error.log;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;                                                                                                                                                                                          
            proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;                                                                                                                                                                                             
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                                                                                                                                                             
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;                                                                                                                                                                              
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }


#    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
#    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sso.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sso.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = sso.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        server_name sso.example.com;

        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Certificate for dynamic subdomains was generated in the following way:

```
certbot --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory -d *.example.com --manual --preferred-challenges dns-01 certonly
```

Right now, when I try to access any subdomain I receive the error that certificate belongs to the main domain.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be answer to your question but a most important thing I recently find out.

I created and used wildcard subdomain on my website . Later, I found out that many browsers do not consider this wildcard SSL certificate.

For example, Chrome ( desktop and Android Application) throw error saying it is "TOO_COMMON_CERT_NAME"

So far, as per my experience, I do not recommend using wildcard certification.
Create manually for each domain/subdomain. You won't regret.